# Obtener un valor desde web.config desde una class library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo una app **ASP.NET** que tiene capa de presentación, datos, negocio, entidades, etc.

Una de las particularidades de la capa de presentación es que en el inicio ejecuta una tarea en 2do plano cuya misión es generar cada X segundos el envío de un mensaje a través de la red. Esta tarea se encuentra encapsulada en otro proyecto del tipo `class library`.

Como parte de este mensaje, estoy necesitando enviar el usuario que se logeó a la aplicación, dato que no tengo cuando inicia la aplicación sino que lo consigo después en una pantalla de login.

En una primera idea para poder pasar este dato a través de una variable global que modificara su valor al momento del login y después, desde la función que envía el mensaje, recuperarlo para poder enviarlo. Esto lo intenté usando el archivo `global.asax` de la aplicación y pude guardar el valor sin problemas, ya que el login está en la aplicación principal MVC.

Necesito poder leer ese archivo desde una `class library` y no encuentro cómo hacer eso, ya que en esa `library` no tengo acceso a las variables de sesión.
¿Alguna otra idea de como poder hacer esta tarea?

Saludos y gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: ¿Necesitas obtener el usuario actual o leer el archivo `Web.config`?

Comment: hola..  necesito leer el web.config, desde un proyecto del tipo class library (capa de negocios), lo del usuario es solo el dato, y ese lo tengo controlado a traves del login.

Comment: Toma en cuenta que lo que suceda en una sesión **vive solo en dicha sesión**, mientras que lo que haya en el `web.config` afecta **a todos los usuarios por igual**, además de que necesita un reinicio en la aplicación. De nuevo, ¿estás seguro que quieres obtener información de ese archivo?

Answer (score 0):

config 
declaramos variable tales como:

```html
<appSettings>
     <add key="Prefix" value="Bkaa6guJnZ5rqwe" />
        <add key="Suffix" value="vNUaBs4ehnTDBvf" />
</appSettings>
```

y en la capa lógica lo leeríamos de la siguiente manera:

```
  string prefi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Prefix"];
  string suffi = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Suffix"];
```

Espero que le ayude ¬V

Answer (score 0):

En principio debes agregar como **referencia** el proyecto `class library` a tu aplicación ASP.NET MVC.

Una vez hecho esto, ya puedes acceder al **web.config** desde tu `class library` mediante la clase **`ConfigurationManager`**. Lo único que debes hacer es **importar como referencia** el ensablado **`System.Configuration`**, que es donde se encuentra la clase `ConfigurationManager`.

Un ejemplo sería este:

En el Proyecto ASP.NET MVC el **Web.config**:

```
<appSettings>

  <add key="Clave" value="Valor"/>

</appSettings>
```

En el Proyecto **class library**:

```
using System;
// Importar este ensamblado
using System.Configuration;

namespace BibliotecaClases
{
    public class Class1
    {
       public Class1()
       {
          var clave = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Clave"];
       }
    }
}
```